# Unable to use the Internet on Windows 8.1, "Internet Access Blocked" displayed everywhere

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, windows-8.1, firewall

I'm having a really strange issue on a Windows 8.1 machine. If I open Chrome or Opera, they say "Your Internet access is blocked", followed by "Firewall or antivirus may have blocked the connection". It's pretty much the exact same problem described here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/internet-access-blocked/d73ba921-7ad9-498a-8c10-43a402b54597

The problem

- Does not occur in Safe Mode
- Occurs with both Wi-Fi and Ethernet
- Only occurs on this one device, and not other devices on the network

Disabling Windows Firewall does not help. The only anti-virus installed is Windows Defender. The Windows network troubleshooter was pretty useless as well.

In CMD, `ping 8.8.8.8` results in "General failure."

Here's an image of the problem, with Opera and Chrome:

[image: blocked]

Comment: Does machine using DHCP or you set it as static IP? Try to power cycle your Internet service provider's modem (unplug it from power at least for a minute then turn it on)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.

“General Failure" appears if the computer doesn't have the proper Internet protocol selected. You may select TCP/IPv4 in the control panel of your computer.

[image: configuration picture1]

Click "Start," and select "Control Panel." Type "Adapter" in the "Search Control Panel" box in the upper right corner and click "View Network Connections" under the Network and Sharing Center tab. Right-click on the network you're using; then click "Properties." Ensure the proper TCP/IP protocol version is checked in the list of optional boxes. At the time of publication, most networks use TCP/IPv4. Don't change any other boxes because they don't affect the ability to ping. Click "Properties," then under the "General" tab, click "Obtain an IP Address Automatically" and "Obtain DNS Server Address Automatically." Then click "OK."

[image: configuration picture2]

If above not work, you can try to reset the TCP / IP Stack.

1.Move the mouse to the right-hand corner of the screen to make the vertical menu bar (charm bar) appear. Click Search.

2.Type “cmd” in the search bar and hit the Enter key on your keyboard.
[image: cmd picture]

3.Right-click on cmd in the search results for Programs, and select **Run as administrator**. Depending on your computer settings, you may be asked to provide an administrator password before you can continue.

4.A black box with a flashing cursor will open; this is the Command Prompt. Type "**netsh int ip reset**" and then hit the Enter key on your keyboard.
[image: reset TCP/IP picture]

5.Wait for the Command Prompt to run through the TCP/IP reset. Once it’s complete, you’ll need to restart your computer to finish.

I have tested my solutions and it works, but if the above not work in your computer, you can try the solutions in the following link. I wish you can solve this problem earlier.

https://appuals.com/fix-general-failure-error-running-ping-commands/

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following steps.
1. Run the command **netsh winsock reset** and press **Enter**.
2. Run the command **ipconfig /all** to check if all the ip configurations are correct.
3. Run the command **ipconfig /flushdns** to see if it helps.
4. And the issue could be caused by the ipv6, we can disable the ipv6ipv4 tunnel try the following command.

**netsh int ipv6 isatap set state disabled**
**netsh int ipv6 6to4 set state disabled**
**netsh interface teredo set state disable**

Or disable ipv6 by the following link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/guidance-for-configuring-ipv6-in-windows-for-advanced-users

5. Try the safe boot and clean boot to see if the issue still occurs.
   (1) Log on as administrator
   (2) **Win+R** and type **msconfig**
   (3) We will get the window of **System Configuration**
   (4) Select **General** tab
   (5) Select **Selective startup**, then uncheck **Load startup items**
   (5) Then select **Services** tab.
   (6) Check **Hide all Microsoft services checkbox**.
   (7) Click **Disable all**
   (8) Select **Startup** tab, and click **Open Task Manager**.
   (9) Make sure that **Startup** tab is selected.
   (10)On the selected tab, right-click each startup program one-by-one to disable them.
   (11)Close Task Manager when done and go back on System Configuration box, click OK.
   (12)Then restart the machine.